# Is it possible to bind data from 2 different tables which has no relation

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like bind grid view with 2 different tables that has no relation. Is it possible to do if so please guide me in achieving that

Comment: Apologies @Dorababu, I tried to answer your question prematurely. I think we'll need a concrete example in order for you to get a decent answer. You say there's no relation between the tables? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Means i am not having any primary key or any other and both are from different databases

Comment: @Dorababu: So the tables don't relate conceptually to each other at all, and you want their contents to be displayed in the same view?

Comment: @Dora, we still need more information. Best give a (simplified) sample of the 2 datasets and how you want it to look.

Comment: I am having 2 tables namely Register and custdetails i want to bind the fields i needed from those 2 tables

Comment: If they were from different tables on the same database you could use a UNION sql clause.

Comment: they are from different databases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick the data from different sources to an iList collection and bind it to a grid.

Comment: Can i have an example or if any link please provide me

Comment: @Dorababu: It would have been easier had you gave some details of the data that you wish to publish. Its so because, normally there won't be any data that one user would like to see in a row of a grid that have no relation to each other. Imagine, someone scrolling through a grid having 10 columns of which the left five tells about browser share in websites and the right five column shows data of price growth in market.

Comment: I am having 2 tables namely custdetails and invoice. In custdetails i will have some  data like email-id , name , customerId and all.. In my invoice i will invoiceId, customerid and other. Now i would like to search for the tools he purchased by entering his mail id which was from 1st table. If exists i would like to bind the data of second table to gridview along with the some fields in  first table data like Name and Address.

Comment: @Dorababu: So you already have a relation between the two tables, the customerId is in both the tables. You can do a query like select Invoice.*, Customer.* from Invoice inner join Customer on customer.customerId = invoice.customerId where customer.emailId=@givenEmailId

Answer (score 1):

First retrieve data from different source in different Dataset. them merge both dataset and bind with gridview.